# How do I lowercase a certain word in my python string? python version 3

Tags: python, replace, version

I have an input, which I know works, and I want to be able to replace certain text in a string, but I need to get around it being case sensitive. I am trying to just lowercase anything that matches my 'find' variable, but I need the best way to do so.

```
# Replace Item Code Filter based on ColorArmor Filter by SethBling
# First Edit by Howzieky_10, correction and bug fixing by medi4

from pymclevel import MCSchematic
from pymclevel import TileEntity
from pymclevel import TAG_Compound
from pymclevel import TAG_Short
from pymclevel import TAG_Byte
from pymclevel import TAG_String
from pymclevel import TAG_Int
from pymclevel import TAG_List
from numpy import zeros


displayName = "Replace Command Block Text"

inputs = (
    ("Find", "string"),
    ("Replace", "string"),
    ("How many times?","string"),
)

def perform(level, box, options):
  find = options["Find"]
  replace = options["Replace"]
  count = options["How many times?"]

  for (chunk, slices, point) in level.getChunkSlices(box):
    for te in chunk.TileEntities:
        px = te["x"].value
        py = te["y"].value
        pz = te["z"].value
        if px < box.minx or px >= box.maxx:
            continue
        if py < box.miny or py >= box.maxy:
            continue
        if pz < box.minz or pz >= box.maxz:
            continue

        if te["id"].value == "Control":
            command = te["Command"].value
            print find
            print command


            command = command.replace(find, replace)
            te["Command"] = TAG_String(command)
            print te["Command"].value
            chunk.dirty = True
```

Comment: What did you tried by now? Show us a little bit of your code.

Comment: If you `replace` a word with upper-case letters, should the replacement use upper-case in the same places (e.g. replacing the first, capitalised word in a sentence)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

This only lower-cases the `'aBc'` found in the string `'ABCaBcabcAbC'`.

```
>>> s = 'ABCaBcabcAbC'
>>> find = 'aBc'
>>> s.replace(find, find.lower())
'ABCabcabcAbC'
```

Using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'{}'.format(re.escape(find)), lambda m:m.group().lower(), s)
'ABCabcabcAbC'
```

If you're looking for exact word then use this regex `\b{}\b.format(find)`.

Comment: Why the `r'{}'.format(find)`? That's just the same as using `find` directly. Did you mean to escape it?

Answer (score 0):

Just lowercase the *whole* string when finding:

```
inputstring.lower().find(your_search_text.lower())
```

Now you are searching case-insensitively through the whole inputstring.

The value referenced by `inputstring` itself is not changed, the `str.lower()` returns a *new* string object with all characters lowercased:

```
>>> inputstring = 'Hello World!'
>>> inputstring.lower().find('hello')
0
>>> inputstring.lower().find('world')
6
>>> inputstring
'Hello World!'
```

Comment: that wouldnt mess up the end result, would it? if not, awesome!

Comment: @Howzieky: It won't. The value referenced by `inputstring` itself is not changed.

Comment: @Howzieky: You cannot use this in a `.replace()` format; I'd use a regular expression instead: `re.sub(re.escape(your_search_text), replacement_text, inputstring, flags=re.IGNORE)` would replace text case-insensitively.